Can't delete a specific entry in my Firebase Realtime Database
I wanted to create a structure like this:
"users": { 
"JkaThVRqp1cBbKxLBk0UzUtu1tJ3": { 
"email": "fwwfw@mail.de",        
"username": "efwfw",        
"favorite teams":[        
"team1", "team2", "team3"        
]},

problem now is, I can't delete this part:
"favorite teams":[
"team1", "team2", "team3"       
]

I tried it with the firebase console and my terminal, with the same result each time. The deletion process looks all the way kinda off, but after the deletion the string just reappears.
- The result after the deletion step

Edit:
<div>
        <select id="region" name="Bundesland Auswahl" title="Bundesland">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Region</option>
          <option value="rg1">Region 1</option>
        </select>
        <select name="club" id="team" title="team">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select a team</option>
        </select>
        <button id="submit" name="newEntry" value="newEntry">Submit</button>
</div>

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const teamSelect = document.getElementById("team");
  const newFavoriteTeams = Array.from(
    teamSelect.selectedOptions,
    (option) => option.value
  );

  const auth = getAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser;

  if (user) {
    const userId = user.uid;
    const favoriteTeamsRef = ref(database, `users/${userId}/favoriteTeams`);

    onValue(favoriteTeamsRef, (snapshot) => {
      const existingFavoriteTeams = snapshot.val() || [];
      const updatedFavoriteTeams = [
        ...new Set([...existingFavoriteTeams, ...newFavoriteTeams]),
      ];

      update(favoriteTeamsRef, { favoriteTeams: updatedFavoriteTeams })
        .then(() => {
          alert("Favorite teams updated successfully.");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert("Error");
        });
    });
  } else {
    alert("No user is signed in.");
  }
});

This the created structure in Firebase the thing I also don't get my head behind, is why the structure is:
"UID":{"favoriteTeams":{"favoriteTeam":"team","team"}}

and not
"UID":{"favoriteTeams":"team","team"}

also just in case, my security rules:
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
    ".write": "auth.uid === $uid || !data.exists()"
  }
},
    "vereine": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    },
    "spiele": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}

I also just noticed a warning in my console:
[Warning] [2024-04-27T11:18:37.683Z]  @firebase/database: (firebase-database.js, line 1)
"FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. @http://127.0.0.1:5500/resource/javascript/index.js:139:45
onValue@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-database.js:1:157844
exceptionGuard@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-database.js:1:19287
eventListRaise@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-database.js:1:142783
eventQueueRaiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-database.js:1:142509
eventQueueRaiseEventsAtPath@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-database.js:1:142131
repoAddEventCallbackForQuery@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-database.js:1:169823
addEventListener@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-database.js:1:169849
@http://127.0.0.1:5500/resource/javascript/index.js:136:12 "

Either the delete is failing, or some other process is putting the data back. There's not a lot more we can say based on what you shared.

I agree with Frank. Can you please edit your question and add the core that provides this behavior? Thanks. Please respond using @AlexMamo

@AlexMamo has just edited my post with all the code snippets. The error message is not understandable with my level of knowledge.

okay, just solved my initial problem. As I wrote the edit, I noticed this part of my RTDB rules: {"rules": {".read": false,".write": false, when I ran a rule simulation it confirmed, that I cannot overwrite the RTDB. I always thought, that the user interface within firebase is above all rules... now that the false entries are deleted I can continue to troubleshoot my code.
I also noticed, if I tried to delete the part of my RTDB the html-site that initially created the entry now gives out the alert: entry created.

Good to hear that you got it working. Note that you said "I tried it with the firebase console and my terminal, with the same result each time. ", but security rules don't affect what you can do in the Firebase console - so I'm not sure what happened there.
